# Equivalent of collection.groupBy in scalaz-streams

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

I have a folder which contain multiple files with names such as `filetype1_ddMMyyyy_hhmm`,  `filetype2_ddMMyyyy_hhmm`

Per each day, there could be multiple files with a different hour and I would need to parse only the one with the highest hour. In a non-reactive stream world, the algorithm can be implemented as a groupBy date, what's its equivalent in scalaz-stream?

Comment: Are the files sorted by date? If not, there is no way of finding the highest hour until the stream halts, so you may as well do this after consuming it.

Comment: I am aware that it will be necessary to traverse all the stream, though I would need to get for each ddMMyyyy__hhmm the filename with the highest hhmm. In SQL that would be such as SELECT MAX(dateTime) group by Date(dateTime) or something similar, are you suggesting to consume the stream and use the collection API, given that anyways I need to consume the stream?

Comment: You cannot emit any partial results while still consuming the stream so why not? If memory is a concern you could do a `scan` with a dictionary, where Date(dateTime) from your example are keys and entries with the currently biggest seen hour are values